# Is there any way to change file FPS in javascript browser or prepare wav conventer to 60FPS videos?

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, wav, audiobuffer

I'm making web application which stores short audio files that have been cut from large video files. User uploads .mp4 file, chooses sound length and here's a little trick. Cutting audio can only be done in backend (correct me if I'm wrong) and sending 700MB data is not good option, so I use code below to decode audio data from .mp4 and then I send it with start and stop params. Backend (Node.js) use's FFMPEG to cut audio and save's  it.

This part works, but i realised that decoded audio from 60FPS video doesn't sound good (not terrible but totally useless in my app). My goal is to avoid third party, especially desktop, apps (like audacity) and allow user to cut revelant part of audio from any mp4 video. Is there any way to convert 60FPS video to 30FPS video (ArrayBuffer) in browser and then decode audio?

```
      fileInput.onchange = event => {
      this.file = event.target["files"][0];
      //.mp4 file
      this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)

      let baseAudioContext = new AudioContext();
      this.file.arrayBuffer().then(buff => {

        baseAudioContext.decodeAudioData(buff,
          success => {
            console.log(success)
            this.bufferToWave(success, 0, success.length);
          },
          err => console.log(err));
      })
    }

  bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, len) {

    var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
      length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
      buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
      view = new DataView(buffer),
      channels = [], i, sample,
      pos = 0;

    // write WAVE header
    setUint32(0x46464952);                         // "RIFF"
    setUint32(length - 8);                         // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157);                         // "WAVE"

    setUint32(0x20746d66);                         // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16);                                 // length = 16
    setUint16(1);                                  // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2);                      // block-align
    setUint16(16);                                 // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

    setUint32(0x61746164);                         // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(length - pos - 4);                   // chunk length

    // write interleaved data
    for (i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
      channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

    while (pos < length) {
      for (i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {             // interleave channels
        sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
        sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767) | 0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
        view.setInt16(pos, sample, true);          // update data chunk
        pos += 2;
      }
      offset++                                     // next source sample
    }

    // create Blob
    //return (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], { type: "audio/wav" }));
    var u = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], { type: "audio/wav" }));

    //temporary part
    //downloading file to check quality
    //in this part sound is already broken, no need to show backend code
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = u;
    a.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();



    function setUint16(data) {
      view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
      pos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
      view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
      pos += 4;
    }
  }
```